# Highcharts not displaying a line, but Jquery seems to be correct

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am building a few graphs based on data I hold in a table. I use the following Jquery to identify my column and pull all the data out and `push` it into an `array`

```
var Platinum = new Array();

$("#GridView3 tr:has(td)").each(function () {
var cell = $(this).find("td:eq(2)");
Platinum.push(parseInt(cell.html()));


});
```

This is working and I can confirm this by using `console.log(Platinum)` which logs the following to the console:

```
[663141, 129271, 133568, 73806, 286348, 0, 101756, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31218, 0, 845702, 37914, 0, 0, 0, 295084, 53218, 63794, 331758, 186627, 3487508, 1275393, 1132994, 875321, 290997, 2521252]
```

I then try use the `Platinum` array in my high-charts, but it doesn't build the line for me?!

But if I copy and paste the hard coded array (which I receive from `console.log` it then works)

Here is the code used to build the graph as well.

```
$(function () {

                var chart;
                /*BUILD PLATINUM CHART*/
                var Platinum = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'Platinum',
                        type: 'line'

                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            cursor: 'pointer'
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Platinum Expected vs Actual',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    exporting: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: Simplicity & CRM',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {

                        categories: ExpectedDate
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        tickInterval: 2000000,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Amount'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },

                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: [ {
                        name: 'Platinum Expected',
                        data: Platinum, //If I hard code this section, it works.
                        color: '#014c73'
                    },{
                        name: 'Platinum Actual',
                        data: PlatinumActual,
                        color: '#8bbc21'
                    }]
                });





            });
```

Please could someone point me in the correct direction as I am not entirely sure how to trouble shoot this anymore.

Also - let me know if you need anymore information.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: you need to be aware which one initialize first, is it the chart or the jquery code above. If the chart initialized first, you can push the data to series programmatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have named your chart variable as "Platinum" as well as the array you are trying to pass in, so try renaming that first of all.

Comment: Hey man, thank you for replying. I completely forgot I had posted this question because I managed to figure it out. And this was this problem indeed :)